# Does "allow remote connections to this server" in sql server impact SSIS packages?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm wondering if anyone has experience with this setting "allow remote connections to this server" in sql server. I am partly responsible for a few hundred sql servers which run SSIS in various ways. Some run it with ssis packages deployed through integration services catalog, and others run the SSIS package from a batch server or even manually from their laptop running visual studio, using a package that connects to our sql server.

A security consultant is saying we need to disable this on every server, no questions asked, but I'm hearing conflicting information. Some would imply any SSIS packages deployed on another server or laptop and connecting to this one, would be denied now. Others say it actually means connections FROM this server, so it would impact ssis packages called from batch servers. Others say it is FROM still, but for some reason wouldn't impact SSIS packages.

Any recommendations on what I should do? Rather than test every possible scenario to appease the security consultant, I would like to be able to rule out a few "always true" situations where we would keep this setting checked. Otherwise I will have to test hundreds of environments just to disprove him. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What version(s) of SQL Server are you running? I believe this setting is ignored as of SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

I basically asked the same question a few years ago, take a look at my thread here: [What does the setting allow remote connections actually do.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/146883/sql-server-allow-remote-connections-to-this-server-option-what-does-this-do)

Answer (score -1):

If you disable "allow remote connections to this server" then you wouldn't be able to connect to SQL server from local VM or any other server. You also wouldn't be able to run SSIS packages remotely. No remote connections would be allowed and the only option would be to login to the server and perform the activities.

Regards,
Shivangi